# publish/subscription with big data Collection

Tags: meteor

I have a very large collection (~40000 documents with ~20-25 fields including array-fields with a set of ~500 items in) and ~2000 subscribers (they are just bots now).

So it's really hard work on client when user subscribe on whole collection (excluding some fields in server's publish) and use Collection.find with custom filters, sort and order

I tryed to use publish with options: i.e. client-defined filters & etc. But in this case I have too many memory leaks on server and epic fail :) after a few hours.

Can anyone advise some publish-subscribe schema for that kind of collections? I do not ask for clear solution but some useful thoughts

Thanks

Comment: The memory leaks you're talking about... any idea where they may come from? You say, that you're using subscriptions with client defined filters. Are you sure, that your subscriptions get cancelled when a user changes their filters?

Comment: Yes all subscriptions got chanceled as expected. But there is a huge work for garbage collector I suppose when subscription's options are change. If I had 2000 users with different options (i.e. filter) it's like I have 2000 different subscriptions

Comment: Nice experiment BTW. I wouldn't be surprised if you were one of the first people to test **Meteor** under such heavy load.

Comment: Ha! Now I am afraid of production with meteor.

Comment: can you please define more precisely the test case you're describing here. I'm interested in details like the number/type of servers you're running on as well as the number of clients that connect simultaneously per server. Also, what amount of data does a typical client require from the server? What exactly do you mean by saying "after a few hours"? :)

Comment: If my team do not mind! I going to post a few issues on github after a short time. We have a single server that runs a meteor app. It's 2 xeon e5 (x8 cores) 64 GB ram. I suppose it's not dependend on a hardware. Our previous solution was based on Java/Oracle, but it was really complicated for administration and support

Comment: No worries :) Keep in mind that **Meteor** is still in beta phase. The performance issues will be addressed sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks. And at the moment Meteor gives fantastic perfomance and a lot of abilities. Waiting for 1.0

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages

It has:

Incremental subscriptions. Downloads only what's needed, not the entire collection at once. Suitable for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT publish all documents. Publish just documents you want to show and use pagination. I wanted to write a tutorial about pagination in Meteor but I don't have much time for it now.

Use Iron Router and its [waitOn](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton) function for client subscribtions.

```
Router.map(function () {
   this.route('postShow', {
      path: '/posts/:page',

      before: function() {
         Session.set('page', this.params.page);
      },

      waitOn: function () {
         //how many documents we want to per page
         var perPage = 50;
         return Meteor.subscribe('posts', {}, {
           //limit
           limit: perPage,
           //we need to compute how many documents to skip
           skip:  perPage * Session.get('page') - perPage
         });
      },

      data: function() {
         return {
            //variable posts available for Handlebars: {{#each posts}}...
            posts: Posts.find()
         }
      } 
   });
});
```

And Publish:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(params, opts) {
   return Posts.find(params, opts);
});
```

Comment: I see. It's common solution I guess. In this case a server-side publishing takes a lot of resources and memory. And with "live search" it's a long time to resubscribe and feth data from cursor (I mean with 2000 users at the time)